# how to call ajax function from javascript with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a billing.php file where I have used autocomplete for an address input.

So I am getting the latitude longitude of the location after address is selected.

Now my task is to calculate the distance from the selected address and the latitude ,longitude taken from session.

For this I need to create one php file which will calculate the distance and return the distance, after getting this distance I need to check if distance is greater than 1 km and if it is greater I need to show a check box showing 2 hour delivery at bottom.

Now I tried to create a calculateDistance function and a ajax function.
But I am not sure how I have to call it from java script function the latitude,longitude variables are not used, I feel I am not passing parameters correct way.

billing.php

```
<div class="margin_tb">

    <?php      session_start(); ?>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="bg_white">
            <form method="post" name="billing_frm" id="cart_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="command"/>
                <div align="center">

                    <h1 align="center">Billing Information</h1>

                    <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="50%">

                        <tr>
                            <td>Address:</td>

                            <td><input type="text" id="saddress1" name="sadd1" size="35" required/></td>
                        </tr>                           
</div>

<script>    

    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
    // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">


    var autocomplete;

    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        var address = place.formatted_address;
        var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

        var mesg = "Address: " + address;
        mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
        mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;

        <?php $store = $_SESSION['oneShop'];?>

        var myVariable = <?php echo(json_encode($_SESSION['oneShop'])); ?>;

        var lat = <?php echo(json_encode($_SESSION['store_latitude'])); ?>;

        var long = <?php echo(json_encode($_SESSION['store_longitude'])); ?>;

            alert (myVariable);

        if(myVariable === 0) {


            calculateDistance(latitude,longitude,lat,long);


        }
        else
            {
                alert('Multiple shops');
            }



        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = componentForm.locality;
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }

    }

    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.

        function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geolocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }

</script>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCP-j5J0xjTzFqTNoGCAxO_c46istGzHSA&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
            show_data(0);
        }
    );

    /*===========================================================
     To calculate distance
     ============================================================*/

     function calculateDistance(latitude,longitude,lat,long) {
    $("#cart_area").append('<div class="preloader"></div>');
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "<?php echo 'http://views/cart/calculateDistance';?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { lat1: latitude,
            lat2 : lat,
            long1: longitude,
            long2: long
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

calculateDistance.php

```
<?php




   $lat1 = $_POST['lat1'];
   $lat2 = $_POST['lat2'];
   $long1 = $_POST['long1'];
   $long2 = $_POST['long2'];

        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
        //$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=". $lat1." , ". $long1." &destination= ". $lat2.",". $long2."&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
        $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

        return $dist;

?>
```

I am a beginner in javascript ,php please help. Thank you.

Comment: edited the code.@Satpal

Comment: You can use the [`$_POST`](https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) _Predefined Variable_ to access your POST data. just like a login form. then you can pass them to your `GetDrivingDistance` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You point is right,you passed the wrong params in ajax function, change your code to:

```
    function calculateDistance(latitude,longitude,lat,long) {
        $("#cart_area").append('<div class="preloader"></div>');
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('cart/calculateDistance');?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { lat1: latitude,
                lat2 : lat,
                long1: longitude,
                long2: long
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

I think it's the wrong use of `this`, have a try. to know more about javaScript `this`,just read [you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes).

Comment: yes that was right.. now that page is getting called but I am not getting the alert which I am showing in on/success of ajax,I am returning the distance I want to get the distance, but it is only showing the progress bar. Can you please check the edited code?.Thank you. @gy134340

Comment: @Sid you can add the error handle methods in ajax call and get the debug messgae, from the current code, I think you can try to change your php code to `return json_encode($dist);` and see what happened.

Comment: tried but still its just showing progress view @gy134340

Comment: @Sid sorry cannot help any more, you can comment all your php backend code and simply `echo json_encode('test');` , and  see the ajax call can get the message or not. also, add the error handle to your ajax calls ```error: function(error){console.log(error);}```